# Access VBA Dimension only storing expected value the first time it is run

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

I've adapted this code from somewhere else. At the click of a button on a form it's meant to tell me the number of non-empty rows in a given range of cells (C1:C500) on an Excel spreadsheet...

```vb
Sub ImportDataFromRange()

Dim excelapp As Excel.Application
Set excelapp = CreateObject("excel.application")
excelapp.Workbooks.Open (Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\MattExcelFile.xls")

Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = excelapp.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C500")

Dim numberofrows As Integer
numberofrows = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myrange)

MsgBox numberofrows
Debug.Print excelapp

excelapp.Quit
Set excelapp = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Command0_Click()

ImportDataFromRange

End Sub
```

On opening MS-Access and running this code via the button I created, it works correctly the first time, but not again after that. Closing and re-opening MS-Access resets the behaviour so it will again work properly the first time it's run after being opened, but then never never again.

On its first run, this is the (correct) data stored in the dimensions:

`excelapp` = "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\MattExcelFile.xls"
`numberofrows` = 4

On subsequent runs, this is the (incorrect) data stored in the dimensions:

`excelapp` = "Microsoft Excel"
`numberofrows` = 500

Can someone give me a hand with the code here so I can run code multiple times within the same MS-Access session and get the correct data in the dimensions each time? Many thanks.

Comment: [Link explains](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-291774.html) the same as Simon's. But Simon's better :) +1 for the "undoubtfully annoying" question, that many programmers may have and may be facing in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just made a couple of changes to your code - I noted them for you - works for me.

As for the excelapp dimension I think it saying 'Microsoft Excel' is correct, if you were to print the wb.Name dimension you would get the workbook name. Not sure why it was giving different dimensions on subsequent runs for you, possibly because you weren't explicitly closing the workbook, but that's a guess.

```
Sub ImportDataFromRange()
Dim excelapp As Object
Set excelapp = CreateObject("excel.application")

' assign the workbook
Dim wb As Object
Set wb = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\tbl_Order_Status.xls")


Dim numberofrows As Integer
' Call function slightly differently
numberofrows = excelapp.Application.counta(wb.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C500"))

' Close and release wb
wb.Close
Set wb = Nothing

MsgBox numberofrows
Debug.Print excelapp

excelapp.Quit
Set excelapp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem stems from the fact that you create your `excelapp` object variable but then you use a different reference (`Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction` instead of `excelapp.WorksheetFunction`) on the line that gets `numberofrows`.

The following (corrected) code works for me:

```
Sub ImportDataFromRange()
Dim excelapp As Excel.Application
Set excelapp = New Excel.Application

excelapp.Workbooks.Open (Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\MattExcelFile.xls")

Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = excelapp.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C500")

Dim numberofrows As Integer
numberofrows = excelapp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myrange)

MsgBox numberofrows
Debug.Print excelapp

Set myrange = Nothing
excelapp.Quit
Set excelapp = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Command0_Click()

ImportDataFromRange

End Sub
```

Comment: works great. Thanks very much. I've added a note to your answer for anyone else who comes across this that they need to make sure that their MS-Access References include the **Microsoft Excel [version] Object Library**, otherwise this way of doing it won't work.